# Matlab area calculation

Tags: matlab, area, ginput

If I have an arbitrary shape (attached is a really simple mock up), how would I estimate the area of the enclosed surface in Matlab.  To get some random points along the curve, I used the ginput command to get a rough estimate of the curve, with unequal spacing between the points.  I want to get an estimate of the area, but I believe the trapz command would overestimate the area due to the overlap (Please correct me if I am wrong here).  Is there a more accurate way to obtain the area?

Thanks!
[image]

[image]

Comment: How did you create the shape?

Comment: What data do you have? `trapz` can be used with a good precision too.

Comment: @NKN I just created a random drawing as an example.  Wouldn't trapz overestimate the area?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you didn't really give enough info to solve the problem entirely, but here's one approach you can take to find the boundary automatically in order to calculate the area:

```
% Get image and convert to logical mask
img = ~im2bw(imread('polyarea.jpg'));

% Fill the hole
img = imfill(img,'holes');

% Get boundary
b = bwboundaries(img);

% Approximate area of boundary
area = polyarea(b{1}(:,1), b{1}(:,2));

% Print area
disp(['Area: ' num2str(area)]); 

imshow(img);
hold on;
plot(b{1}(:,2),b{1}(:,1),'go');
```

The idea is you have an input, you form a logical mask, get the boundary of the mask, and then you can approximate the area enclosed by the boundary by using `polyarea`.

The output is:

[image]

```
Area: 228003
```

Additionally, you could also use `regionprops(img,'Area')` which outputs:

```
ans = 

    Area: 229154
```

Comment: Thanks for the time and answer.  Would the same process apply to an open curve?  For instance, if my test image did not have a "base," (just a curve) could I apply the imfill option?  Could you speak to which of these methods would provide a more accurate solution?

Comment: @Cyrus can you post an additional image in the question?

Comment: I just meant if the base of the first image was not available.  I added a 2nd image with the base erased.